# Modified box dimension of a countable set.

Tags: fractals, dimension-theory-analysis

I am working from Falconer's book Fractal Geometry: Mathematical Foundations and Applications (which seems to be the go-to book). I have reached the section of the modified box-counting dimensions, which are defined as

$$\underline{\dim}_{MB}(F)=\inf\left\{\sup_{i}\left\{\underline{\dim}_{B}(F_{\color{red}i})\right\}:F\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}F_{i}\right\} \qquad \text{(lower)}$$

and

$$\overline{\dim}_{MB}(F)=\inf\left\{\sup_{i}\left\{\overline{\dim}_{B}(F_\color{red}i)\right\}:F\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}F_{i}\right\} \qquad \text{(upper)}$$

where $\underline{\dim}_{B}$ is the lower box dimension and $\overline{\dim}_{B}$ is the upper box dimension.

I am trying to show an example of a countable set $F$ for which $\dim_{B}(F)>0$ and $\dim_{MB}(F)=0$ (after proving that $\dim_{MB}(F)=0$ for any countable set $F$).

**My work so far:** I have decided to use the set $F=\{0,1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\ldots\}$. I know that $\dim_{B}(F)=\frac{1}{2}$ (this is proven in the book), but I don't know how to calculate the modified box dimensions of $F$. Is someone able to start me off? Thank you.

Comment: You had an extremely import typo in your question. I've edited it to correct the typo - note the $F_{\color{red}i}$ with the red $\color{red}i$ which you didn't have in your original post. Does that make it a bit easier?

Comment: Ah yes, thank you very much. I think so, if I take the box dimensions of each 'broken' up piece of $F$ (so each point?) I should get $0$ yes?

Comment: *Exactly*! That should make it easy to prove that any countable set has modified box counting dimension zero. Thus, any countable, dense subset of $\mathbb R^n$ provides an example of a set with well-defined box counting dimension $n$ and modified box-counting dimension zero.